# Should I take shahada if I already pray salah?

Tags: shahada

Before officially converting, I started practicing things like praying 5 times a day and avoiding pork to prepare myself and make sure that it was something I could commit to.  After starting to pray salah for a few weeks, I looked at the shahada again, and I realized that I've already said it many times during salah. I know it's my decision, but do you personally think I should take shahada anyway at the Mosque? I don't feel there would be much meaning to it since I've already said it this entire time without realizing.

Comment: Intention matters, you must have said it with the intention to accept Islam.